# How to limit Input characters generically through out Angular project?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, forms

I need to apply limit on all inputs throughout the project . I tried with angular pipes but not get required result also by creating generic form component but different inputs have different, styling and usage that is why I am still looking for simple solution to solve this issue . your effort will be appreciate. Thankyou

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can not help you to correct your mistakes if you don't show us what code you wrote. Thats why you need to create a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

***maxlength*** could help you

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="10">
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp